# How to decluster negative values

Tags: r

I have a dataset set containing negative values, and I want to perform GPD analysis on it. The data is on the negative real line, with values closer to zero being considered extreme (the values I want to perform analysis on). I've found a decluster command in the extRemes package, but when I input my threshold excesses, it returns values with a greater absolute value instead of values greater than.

So if I have a vector of data (-5, -7, -9, -10, -11)
and I have a threshold of -8
the output vector is a little like this (-9, -10, -11)
but I would like the output vector (-5, -7)

The command I used is

```
as.numeric(decluster(frame[,1], threshold = u, method="intervals"))
```

Where frame[,1] is a vector of negative values on the negative real line.

Comment: Not sure I understand the complexity of this ... if `vec <- c(-5, -7, -9, -10, -11)`, then `vec[vec > -8]` seems straight-forward. If you need them grouped based on consecutive negative numbers meeting that condition, then we could easily use `rle` (run-length encoding) to help with this.

Comment: But ... perhaps you can try double-negation? `-as.numeric(decluster(-frame[,1], threshold = u, method="intervals"))`? (I'm not familiar with `decluster`, just a guess.) Perhaps `threshold=-u` instead?

Comment: To clarify, the decluster function declusters values where the absolute value exceeds the absolute value of the threshold. I would like it do decluster values where the actual value exceeds the actual threshold. I would like to perform declustering on the values closest to zero.